# Auto increment in views table

Tags: views

I have views with table display, the table consist of two column(name[string], salary[float]).
How can i set a auto increment for the table rows?
like this want i want [image] .
Thanks.

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You need to add a new field to the view, and choose the "Global" filter from the available drop down.

Then choose the "Global: View result counter" type:

[image]

That wiill give you a counter as a field which you can put into whichever column in the table is appropriate for what you need.