# How to print ordered list number in Node Full view

Tags: nodes

I have a views page with nodes in ordered list. I need to show the row number in the node in Full View. I don't know if it is possible.

Example:

1. Michael Jordan
2. Magic Johnson
3. Kobe Bryant
4. etc.

I want that when I see the node, for example Kobe Bryant, it says "Kobe Bryant is number **3**".
If I see Jordan's node it says "Michael Jordan is number **1**", etc.

How can I print this number?

Comment: How is the view sorting those nodes?

Comment: Sort criteria
(Vote results) Vote results: Value (desc)

Comment: Ah so it's vote related. So voting API? Which module are you using for voting? The best way is probably querying the vote results from the database as opposed to rendering that view and then checking the results.

Comment: Are you using rate module / fivestar module for voting ?

Comment: sorry i forgot to mention this, yes i am using fivestar :)

Comment: Duplicate of: [Auto increment in views table](http://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/27089/auto-increment-in-views-table)